# "Бог не выдаст, свинья не съест"

Tags: фразеология

Хотелось бы узнать происхождение этой поговорки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов.

Во первых христианский. По преданию, когда младенца Христа прятали в хлеву от Ирода, то лошадь зарывала его в солому, а свинья разрывала обратно.

Второй, возможно древнее и связан с отношением к свинье как к нечистому животному, проявлению "демонической" сущности и плохому предзнаменованию, особенно в дороге.

Есть еще одна поговорка - Конь не выдаст, враг не съест. Она так же встречается, хотя и редко.

Answer (score 1):

Реально здесь - указание на вполне возможное в древней крестьянской жизни событие. Сейчас уже почти никто не знает, что именно свинья способна на самом деле съесть ребёнка. Свиньи прожорливы, и, когда голодны, то могут есть разную мелкую живность, если смогут её поймать. Цыплёнка, например, могут съесть. Сомнительно, чтобы свинья могла съесть взрослого человека: всё-таки свинья - не хищник, у неё нет обыкновения прежде всего вцепляться в горло; даже мертвецки пьяный очнётся, когда его начнут кусать, и отгонит свиней. А вот малыша или, тем более, младенца свинья съесть может. У Некрасова: "Загрызли свиньи Дёмушку!" Естественно, лучшее, что могла сделать мать, - это не оставлять ребёнка одного, носить его с собой. Но это можно делать не всегда. Вот и оставляли матери дома детей, молясь Богу и уповая на то, что без Божьей воли ничего не случается. Ну, а если беда на самом деле случилась - значит, такова была Божья воля...

Comment: Ditto. У того же Некрасова:  

  "А у солдатки Аксиньи    
  Девочку - было ей с год -     
  Съели проклятые свиньи"